# Button close on imageview from camera or gallery

Tags: android, button, uiimageview, imageview, android-imageview

Good day!
It is necessary to add a button to delete the imageview (picture). I do not know how to do it. Thx for help =3

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1 && null != data) {
        decodeUri(data.getData());
    }
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photka);


        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");


        image.setImageBitmap(photo);

    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAlDG.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAlDG.png

Comment: Are you trying to delete the Imageview or the photo from camera?

Comment: It would be better if you could be more specific on question or where exactly are you stuck.

Comment: I want delete Imageview

Comment: How right initialize overlay button from resource? and locate the button in the upper right corner of the image

Comment: I have 2 screen, my post below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android RelativeLayout align center of one view on top right corner of another view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400348/android-relativelayout-align-center-of-one-view-on-top-right-corner-of-another-v)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the ImageView with any of the below options

1. You can set the visibility of the ImageView to Gone when button is clicked like this

   ```
   final ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photka);

   Button removeImageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button_id);
   removeImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
   });
   ```
2. You can remove the ImageView from its parent View like this

   ```
   final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.root_parent);

   final ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photka);

   Button removeImageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button_id);
   removeImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           parent.removeView(image);
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: thx for this, but i want right located button (remove) on imageview in the upper right corner

Answer (score 0):

add code for my activity

ImageView close = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.close) ;
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photka);

image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            close.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Answer (score 0):

final ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photka);
            final ImageView close = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.close) ;

```
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");


        image.setImageBitmap(photo); 
        image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
        close.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                close.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return;
            }
        });
```

need add remove from stack together with Visibility.Gone